# Digital signing with qdigidoc4 (Estonian ID card software) under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, signature, smartcard

When trying to use qdigidoc4 (version 4.2.4.71) on Ubuntu 20.04, and trying to sign a container, signing fails (both with ID card and Mobile ID) and I get the following message:

```
ASiC_E.cpp:347 Failed to sign container.
SignatureXAdES_LT.cpp:227 Could not find certificate issuer 'CN=ESTEID-SK 2015,organizationIdentifier=NTREE-10747013,O=AS Sertifitseerimiskeskus,C=EE' in certificate store.
```

Also viewing signed containers fails (all signatures are marked as "unknown").

How to run qdigidoc4 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my understanding (reading this [bug report](https://github.com/open-eid/libdigidocpp/issues/341)), the Estonian root certificate is invalid (but probably not in a security-critical way), and OpenSSL 1.1.1f (used in Ubuntu 20.04) is stricter about the validation than OpenSSL 1.1.1e was. But OpenSSL 1.1.1g reverted this and again accepts the Estonian root certificate. The problem can be fixed by installing OpenSSL 1.1.1g. However, OpenSSL 1.1.1g is not packaged for Ubuntu yet.

Installing the Debian versions works:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1g-1_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1g-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i openssl_1.1.1g-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1g-1_amd64.deb
```

**I do not know if this breaks something else.** But signing and verifying with qdigidoc4 is successful again on my system with this change.