# Failed to send time-stamp request in DigiDoc4 client

Tags: 20.04, smartcard

In installed the Estonian E-ID card tool DigiDoc4 Client (command `qdigidoc4`) according to the [official instructions](https://www.id.ee/en/article/ubuntu-id-software-installation-updating-and-removal/) under Ubuntu 20.04.

Now when trying to sign a document with this tool, I get the following error message:

```
ASiC_E.cpp:371 Failed to sign container.
TS.cpp:116 Failed to send Time-stamp request
```

How to sign the document when this happens?

Comment: Based on the answer given this has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some issues with the Estonian E-ID software under Linux, most recently one where it would need a newer package of OpenSSL than provided by Ubuntu 20.04 (discussed in [this AskUbuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1247162)). So, assuming this is a software bug is reasonable, but in this case the solution is simpler:

This happened today simply because of **server availability issues** of the Estonian government's official timestamping server. Solution:

1. Make sure your Internet connection is working. If necessary, fix it and try again.
2. If that's not the cause, just wait for 10 minutes and try again. If that helps, it was a server availability issue of the timestamping server itself. Worked for me today. Since there were no reports about this error message online so far, it seems that the timestamping service is generally stable.
3. If their timestamping server is down for a longer time, you might be able to use an alternative timestamping service according to [these instructions](https://www.id.ee/en/article/for-organisations-that-sign-large-quantities-of-documents-using-digidoc4-client/#in-order-to) (not tested yet).

**Notes:**

- The default URL of the Estonian timestamping service is `http://dd-at.ria.ee/tsa`, as per the [official list of URLs contacted by the E-ID software](https://www.id.ee/en/article/list-of-urls-contacted-internally-by-the-id-card-software/). You can't test its availability by typing it into the browser, because that's a GET request and will lead to "404 Not Found" even when the server is up and running, that is, answering correctly to POST requests.
- The code section generating this error message is in [libdigidoccpp, file TS.cpp, line 116](https://github.com/open-eid/libdigidocpp/blob/a3f6079/src/crypto/TS.cpp#L116).